# Dynamic initialization of object with constructor Vs. new in c++?

Tags: c++, object, memory-management, dynamic

What is difference between these two statements with respect to **dynamic memory initialization of object** :-

> class_name *obj = new class_name;
>
> class_name obj = class_name();

Answer (score 3):

The first example works roughly like this:

- operator new is called and memory allocated on the heap
- the default constructor for class_name is called and thus the object pointed to is initialized.

The second example:

- a temporary object A is created (right hand side of the assignment).
- an object B is created (default constructor; left hand side)
- the contents of A is overwritten by that of object B - this done by calling the assignment operator
- A becomes destroyed.

**Edit: Actually, what I've written for the second example above, is not right** (maybe it's not wrong, too). I don't know the standard here, but with VC12 (optimizations off) the code doesn't create an temporary object. It just calls the default constructor for an object on the stack. And the code doesn't compile if there's a private assignment operator - as James writes in his comment.

Comment: The explication for the second example is completely wrong.  There is _no_ assignment in either of his examples.

Comment: Memory _could_ be allocated on the heap is more correct. New can fail.

Comment: in addition to what @JamesKanze says, as I recall, when the types on both sides are the same in a copy initialization, then copy elision must be performed (i.e. there is no temporary).

Comment: @Alf You're right, and I'd forgotten about that.  When the types are identical, there is _no_ copy; IIUC, there is not even a need for an accessible copy constructor.

Comment: @Alf But both VC++ and g++ say that the accessible copy constructor is needed.  I'm not sure if it's me who's reading the standard wrong, or them.

Answer (score 2):

The first defines a pointer to `class_name`, dynamically
allocates an object of that type, and initializes the pointer
with its address.  The lifetime of the object itself is until
you explicitly delete it.  If the `class_name` has a default
constructor, that is called; otherwise, the object is not
initialized.

The second defines an instance of a `class_name`; formally, it
constructs a temporary of that type, using the default
constructor if one is defined, or zero initialization if not,
and copy constructs the defined instance from that.  The
compiler is allowed to elide this copy construction, however
(and all that I know of do), and construct the defined object
directly.  (It must still verify that there is an accessible
copy constructor, however.)  The lifetime of the defined object
is until it goes out of scope.

In general, we avoid the first form, unless we really need the
explicit lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

First is dynamically allocated. Second is statically allocated, but value initialized.

Comment: You mean to say in second case value will initialized at run time ?

Comment: Members of an aggregate(POD) class will be initialized at run time. Without value initialization, members of a POD object would not be initialized. I dont know if there is any difference for a class with a user defined constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class_name *obj = new class_name;
```

creates an object on the heap, you will need to delete it via `delete` to avoid memory leaks.

This:

```
class_name obj = class_name();
```

creates an object on the stack, the object will be deleted when it goes out of scope.

Comment: But in cases memory will initialized at run time isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, for both situations the memory is allocated and initialized at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have related the assignment/question text correctly. It's subtle. The "dynamic" has nothing to do with the dynamic allocation in the first statement.

The `()` parenthesis ensures a C++03 **value initialization**, which for a POD type means zeroing. Without it (first statement), if the class is a POD its members needs not be initialized. I would have to check the standard for the more general case, but I think, now that you know what the question is about, that's something you can do on your own.